# influxdb flux lookup function

Tags: influxdb, flux

I have a table in a MySQL DB containing a model_name as key and a model_desc as a secondary column.

```
| model1 | Phone |
| model2 | Tablet |
```

In influxdb I have a bucket with a series in which model_name is a label

```
| username | model_name | last_connected |
```

I have to join these two so for each event in influxdb I can associate it with a model_desc. If there is no match, I want to set model_desc to something like 'unknown'

I got as far as using join on both queries but since join is explicitly 'inner' I only see the intersection. I'd require something like an outer join or a lookup that returns either a match or an 'unknown' for non-matching rows.